# How to write a batch with a common header in it

Tags: javascript, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

Im in need to exclude all the JavaScript files which has a header "XYZ" inside it. if the pattern "XYZ" is present inside the file, then the batch should rename the file as *.js.exclude. I have almost 189 JS files present inside the sources which are inside different sub folders as well. Any help to write a batch which can do the above are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use `findstr`.
`/m` to get the filenames
`/s` to process subfolders too
(`/i` to ignore capitalization, if needed)

Put a `for` loop around it to rename the files:
use `%%a` for the full path/filename
use `%%~nxa` for filename and extension only
surround your filenames with quotes to handle paths/filenames with spaces
for the same reason, use `"delims="`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /s /m "XYZ" *.js') do ECHO ren "%%a" "%%~nxa.exclude"
```

After debugging, remove `ECHO` if the output is ok.

Comment: Is this script that I can run directly from CMD with folder path kept or should I create a bat file with this script. Running from cmd is not working - Giving a message that %%a is unexpected

Comment: How can I run this as a .BAT file ??
I would need to run this a tool which can take the predefined path and do the above